# Need a word for "Should not have happened' with a negative context

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I'm looking for a word to mean "should not have happened."  I'm trying to relate this situation; two paths - one positive, one negative - with the same end result, and the negative path was taken.

Help please! Thank You!

Update:
OK, so the 2 paths being: my daughter had a cut by her eye, the doctor chose stitches instead of suture glue, and the ensuing pain, torn stitches, and inability to remove them all could have been avoided if she'd just used the glue in the first place. The sentence I am trying to finish is: "Based on the open scarring left behind from the use of sutures, the whole experience seems ***_*_**."

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you looking for something like a "happy accident"?

Comment: How exactly would the word be used in the situation you describe?

Comment: Maybe *All's well that ends well*. But to really have any idea we would need to know more about what you are trying to accomplish with this word or expression with more detail than "two paths -- one positive, one negative"

Comment: Do you want this answered [the hard way or the easy way?](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+hard+way+or+the+easy+way%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) The implication being you'll end up in the same place whichever way you go, but one way will be much more unpleasant/difficult than the other.

Comment: duh, Pointless!  Sometimes it just takes a little time and bouncing around to get the proper word to jog.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4):

Barring a more detailed example, I think that ***"regrettable"*** could be a good fit.

"The results from taking the wrong path were ***regrettable***.

From the [Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regrettable):

> "Regrettable": causing sadness or disappointment; deserving regret
>
> Examples of REGRETTABLE:
>
> "His decision to quit is regrettable."
>
> "It was a regrettable mistake."

Comment: Death is regrettable, but not avoidable. Being late for an appointment because you choose to walk is regrettable and avoidable.

Answer (score 1):

I like **preventable** or **unnecessary** in your sentence.  Both have very negative connotations without seeming rude.  You could just go with **avoidable** too.

> preventable:     capable of being prevented; "conscious of preventable
>   human suffering"

Answer (score 0):

I would use ill-advised, misguided, wrong-headed, or mistaken.

> "Based on the open scarring left behind from the use of sutures, the whole experience 
>   seems **ill-advised**."
>
> "Based on the open scarring left behind from the use of sutures, the whole experience seems **misguided**."

While not an answer specifically to the question (it is more verbose and adds a phrase instead of a word), I would phrase the sentence as follows:

> "Based on the open scarring left behind from the use of sutures, the whole experience seems **needlessly invasive and not in the best interests of the patient.**"

Comment: This sentence has been bugging me for a couple days, and I do believe I like your more verbose version better than the original.  Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the awkwardness lies in some cross-wiring: the two paths do *not* lead to the same end result--that's what defines one option as preferable. But that only made the *decision* regrettable, not the "whole experience". The "whole ordeal" includes the involuntary accident outside the medical decision-making, rendering 'regret', 'pointless' and 'avoidable' kind of unmusical. (You can't regret a tornado or refer to sneezing as pointless.)

"What made the whole experience so disappointing was the avoidable scarring left behind by the unnecessary sutures."

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question. To leave constructive criticism or to clarify a question (or answer), earn the reputation required to [comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

I would use the 1st, conveys the point you're trying to make: (could have been) Avoided / (was) Avoidable / (was) Needless.